# PyQt4: QTableView is very slow

Tags: python, performance, pyqt4, qtableview

Hi I built a GUI using PyQt4 and it has a QTableView  but it's very slow.
Whenever I click on one of a cells it opens a popup(very slowly).
But it's also quiet slow when scrolling.
I inherited QtCore.QAbstractTableModel:

```
class RegressionTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

ROW_BATCH_COUNT = 15

def __init__(self, data=None, header=None, parent=None):
    super(RegressionTableModel, self).__init__(parent)
    if data is None:
        self._data = []
    else:
        self._data = data
    self.tooltips = {}
    if header is None:
        self._header = []
    else:
        self._header = header
    self.rows_loaded = RegressionTableModel.ROW_BATCH_COUNT

def rowCount(self, parent=None):
    return len(self._data)

def columnCount(self, parent=None):
    return len(self._data[0]) if self.rowCount() else 0

def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
        return QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
    if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
        if 'Pass' in self._data[index.row()][index.column()]:
            return QtGui.QColor(193, 204, 137)
        elif 'Fail' in self._data[index.row()][index.column()]:
            return QtGui.QColor(176, 102, 96)
        elif any(x in self._data[index.row()][index.column()] for x in ['pre-test', 'post-test']):
            return QtGui.QColor(106, 125, 142)
    if role == QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole:
        if 'Pass' in self._data[index.row()][index.column()]:
            return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
        elif 'Fail' in self._data[index.row()][index.column()]:
            return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white)
        elif any(x in self._data[index.row()][index.column()] for x in ['pre-test', 'post-test']):
            return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white)
    if role == QtCore.Qt.FontRole:
        if any(x in self._data[index.row()][index.column()] for x in ['Pass', 'Fail', 'pre-test', 'post-test']):
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setBold(True)
            return font
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        if 0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount():
            if 0 <= index.column() < self.columnCount():
                return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
    if role == QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole:
        try:
            operation_params = ""
            for line in self.tooltips[index.row()][index.column()]:
                operation_params += line + "\n"
            return operation_params
        except KeyError:
            return "Nothing to see"

def headerData(self, index, orientation, role):
    if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return QtCore.QVariant("Client %s" % index)
    elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return QtCore.QVariant(index)
    return QtCore.QVariant()
```

I heard that it might work slowly and that it is also can be solved with custom model. But it didn't for me.

Comment: I use QTableViews a lot and don't find them particularly slow even with 10s of 1000s of rows and dozens of columns.  Can you be more specific about what slow means?  When you say "popup" do you mean the tooltip?  There doesn't seem to be any code here to cause a popup when you click.  Nothing in this code seems like it could run slowly.  I suspect the slowness is neither in this code nor the QTableView itself.

Comment: Unless there is something weird in your data array.  Are the elements really long lists, or something for which `in` would be slow?  Note that the `in` operation is O(n) for sequence types.

Comment: By slow I mean that when I change into the tables context and hover over one of the lines it takes a couple of seconds until the tooltip shows up. But after it does it works kind of ok I guess still not fast but better.
And no the data array isn't weird it's just a string.

Comment: The tooltip has a deliberate delay (not sure how long but 2 seconds sounds right).  You could try changing the tooltip delay in the style sheet.